# ingresar a modem con cURL

Tags: php, login, curl

encontré algunos ejemplos de login con cURL y estoy utilizando este...

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://myhost/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

$output = curl_exec($ch);

if($output === FALSE){
echo 'cURLL Error:'.curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);

print_r($output);



?>
```

al ejecutarlo solo me imprime un uno "1" y nada mas...

lo que estoy intentando es ingresar a un modem GSM que tengo... algún consejo?

gracias!

Comment: la url que estas consumiendo, envia los parametros get o  post?

Comment: eso es lo que aun no averiguo como hacer... :( tiene un digest login...

Comment: Pero cuando accedes via web, logras entrar al modem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Le recomiendo realizar el login (digest login) con las herramientas para desarrolladores de Google Chrome activas, así podrá visualizar los headers (por medio de la pestaña NetWork) para tratar de replicarlos vía Curl.